# minimum bounding ellipsoid example does not work in 12.1.1.0

Tags: bugs

I am surprised that WRI never checks previous examples before shipping new versions. The following example is mentioned and highlighted on the webpage. It does not work in 12.1.1.0 and as far as I remember it used to work in older version 12.0 perhaps. Does someone else has trouble running this example with a fresh kernel. I have filed a bug report nevertheless Case number 4696657

https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/convex-optimization/minimal-bounding-ellipsoid.html?product=mathematica

I get this output below:

[image]

Comment: Likely a typo: try `ConicOptimization` instead of `NMinimize`.

Comment: Or `SemidefiniteOptimization`.  Contact WTS.

Comment: @user64494 Did you pay attention that in this example we minimize nonlinear function `-Log[Det[a]]`, while with `SemidefiniteOptimization[]` and `ConicOptimization[]` we minimize  the linear objective function? Also I have tested that this example works fine in v. 12.0.0.0, but it is not working in v.12.1.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

The issues seems to be have been resolved in `V13.0.0`

[image: resolved]